# Softlayer api: Why is SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData interface data returned is empty?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, bandwidth

I'm developing about softlayer api. I got bandwidth informations by SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData interface. This interface is normal in yesterday.  But today I get the bandwidth of data is all the []. So we have a problem of charging now. Is there something wrong with the interface ?

Regards~

```
    def get_amount_of_used_bandwidth(self, type, begin_date, end_date, instance_id, internal=300, default_log_type = 'sl_api'):
    '''
    Get amount of used bytes
    :param type:
        bandwidth_public_in
        bandwidth_public_out
        bandwidth_private_out
        bandwidth_private_in
    :param begin_date: 2016-09-01T00:00:00+8:00
    :param end_date: 2016-09-22T00:00:00+8:00
    :param interval integer  300, 600, 1800, 3600, 43200 or 86400 seconds
    :param instance_id:24401607
    :return:
    [
        {
            'counter': 96563.0,
            'type': 'publicOut_net_octet',
            'dateTime': '2016-03-31T00:05:00-06:00'
        },
        ...
    ]
    '''

    if not self.check_date(begin_date):
        raise AttributeError('Invalid date')

    if not self.check_date(end_date):
        raise AttributeError('Invalid date')

    metric_info = self.sl_virtual_guest.getMetricTrackingObject(id=instance_id)
    metric_tracking_object_id = metric_info['id']

    if type == 'bandwidth_public_out':
        types = [
                {
                    "keyName": "PUBLICOUT",
                    "name": "publicOut",
                    "summaryType": "sum"
                }
        ]

    elif type == 'bandwidth_public_in':
        types = [
                {
                    "keyName": "PUBLICIN",
                    "name": "publicIn",
                    "summaryType": "sum"
                }
        ]
    elif type == 'bandwidth_private_out':
        types = [
                {
                    "keyName": "PRIVATEOUT",
                    "name": "privateOut",
                    "summaryType": "sum"
                }
        ]
    elif type == 'bandwidth_private_in':
        types = [
                {
                    "keyName": "PRIVATEIN",
                    "name": "privateIn",
                    "summaryType": "sum"
                }
        ]
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Invalid type')

    data_repo = self.sl_metric_tracking_object.getSummaryData(begin_date, end_date, types, internal,
                                                              id=metric_tracking_object_id)


    return data_repo
```

Comment: Did you compare the result with the Control portal page? If you get [] it means that there aren't any data recorded for that date.

Comment: can you check if using the control portal you are getting empty results as well? the control portal uses the same method to get the bandwidth so it may an issue with your machine, please review that machine using control portal and also try using other machines

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had compared the result with the Control portal page.  It is same.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is not with the API for me it working fine, the issue is with your machine. So I suggest you to submit an ticket to softlayer in order they review your machine.